# Isn't something missing in [expr.cond]/2?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[expr.cond]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#2):

> 2  If either the second or the third operand has type void, one of the
>   following shall hold:
>
> (2.1) — The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly
>   parenthesized) throw-expression (8.17); the result is of the type and
>   value category of the other. The conditional-expression is a bit-field
>   if that operand is a bit-field.
>
> (2.2) — Both the second and the third operands have type void; the
>   result is of type void and is a prvalue. [ Note: This includes the
>   case where both operands are throw-expressions. —end note ]

Consider the case where the second operand has type void, but it's not a throw-expression and the third operand is a throw-expression. Would this case fall under (2.1) or (2.2)?

Comment: You seem to be describing **(2.1)** precisely.  It's not the `void` operand that throws, it's the other operand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 2.1 has the condition:

> (the second operand is a *throw-expression*) XOR (the third operand is a *throw-expression*)

Case 2.2 has the condition:

> (the second operand has type `void`) AND (the third operand has type `void`)

So if exactly one operand is a *throw-expression* and the other has type `void`, that's case 2.1. The fact that the other operand has type `void` means that the result of the conditional expression has type `void` (due to the clause after the semicolon), but it doesn't change the fact that we're in case 2.1.